# Create file that can not be modified android

Tags: android, file, certificate, x509certificate

I am developing an Android project in which I have some information that I have to send to a Web Service where it is "signed".

In addition to sending the information I have to generate a file with the date, time and all that information. The problem is that this file can not be modified since it must be a file to validate the information that has been sent and it is to verified if the data has not been modified by third parties. Let's say it's an object to sign what we've sent.

I have been told that this could be solved with Tokens, but from what I have been reading the Tokens serve to authenticate against a server and not save a file with that information.

Any idea that I can use to generate this kind of files?

A greeting.

Edit:

Another possible solution would be to generate a PDF file at the moment with all the information and sign it with a .pfx certificate.

At the moment I have not found a way to sign the PDF from Android.

Comment: You can digitally sign that file with a key generated on your device (e.g using AndroidKeyStore). If someone modifies the file, the signature verification will fail

Comment: @pedrofb you mean sign the PDF File? I will search information about it. Thanks

Comment: No, you do not need a PDF at all. Simply create a detached signature on the binary content of the file using a RSA key pair that you have previously generated in the AndroidKeyStore